# How to change parameter inside the function on different buttons click

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 buttons

```
<div id='dwbuttons' class="cards">
    <div>
      <div class="image-div">some image here</div>
      <a id="Autotune" class='Autotune' href="whait.html" target="_blank">autotune</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image-div">some image here</div>
      <a id="Complete" class='Complete' href="whait.html" target="_blank">Cmplete</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image-div">some image here</div>
      <a id="FLstudio"  class='FLstudio' href="whait.html" target="_blank">FLstudio</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

each button should downloads different type of file and all this handles one fuction (downloadURI)

```
let Auto = document.getElementById('Autotune')
let complete = document.getElementById('Complete')
let flstudio = document.getElementById('FLstudio')

let buttons = document.getElementById("dwbuttons")


function downloadURI(uri, name) {

    name = ''
    uri = ''

    let link = document.createElement("a");

    link.setAttribute('download', name);
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();

}


buttons.onclick = function(){
  setTimeout(
    downloadURI, 1000
  )
}
```

**How can I change the parameters of "name" and 'uri' to 'name = flstudio' and "uri = flstudio" when related button is clicked?**

What i need:
When button 1 is clicked - name = Autotune, uri = autotune

When button 2 is clicked - name = Complete, uri = complete

...

Im really stuck here

I can make 3 different functions with name and uri i needed and then another 3 to call them onclick, but it will be a mess,  if assume I will have 15 buttons. Maybe array is a way to go here, but i dont have enough knowledge yet.

Comment: You can store the data in `data-` attributes and then read it from `event.currentTarget.dataset` in your click handler

Comment: Your code doesn't look right, you are resetting the params ```uri``` and ```name``` in your function to be empty strings.

Comment: please search for event delegation and event.target .. there are surely milions of qa like this one

Comment: Could do inline onClick();
So something like:
<a id="Complete" class='Complete' onClick="downloadURI('Complete','complete')" href="whait.html" target="_blank">Cmplete</a>

Comment: Use `bind`  method to add parameter on event call back function. `callbackfn.bind(this,"mydata")`;

Comment: too many easy ways to do this, just search for it and change values of params before calling your function or do an onclick on every button and send different values to your function

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for your suggestions, I'll take a look at them! I`m yet too fresh for this language, I guess

Edit: dataset did work for me, thx!

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommed would be the following.

Give all your buttons the same class, and give each button `data-` attribute, cotaining the information you need. Then, with simply JQuery, you can retrieve those, for example, on-click.

```
<a class='button Autotune' href="whait.html" data-name="autotune" data-uri="example.com" target="_blank">autotune</a>
<a class='button Autotune' href="whait.html" data-name="autotune2" data-uri="example2.com" target="_blank">autotune</a>
<a class='button Autotune' href="whait.html" data-name="autotune3" data-uri="example3.com" target="_blank">autotune</a>
```

The JQuery would be something like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').on('click', function(){
      $(this).attr('data-name');
      $(this).attr('data-uri');
   });
});
```

This way you can have only one function, that can do all the hard work for you.
Note that this function only retrieves data from each button, you will need to extend this function as you need to.